# How do you define a function to return the sum of two functions?

Tags: python, function

I am working on a Python lesson about functions.
I created a simple square root function:

```
def sqrt(x):
     return x ** 0.5

print(sqrt(9))
```

Now, I wanted to create a function which can call **sqrt** (as a parameter) twice:

```
def add_function(func, x):
    return((func, x) + (func, x))

    print(add_function(sqrt, 9))
```

However, this gets a syntax error.  In my mind, the `add_function` should return the `sqrt` function with the argument 9 added to the same.

I am looking for a some enlightenment.

Comment: What do you mean by 'adding'? Show us the intended output.

Comment: `(func, x)` is not how you call a function.

Comment: Google for the keyword higher-order function or maybe *functions are first class citizens*.

Comment: change it to `return(func(x) + func(x))`

Comment: Thank you @downshift ! I appreciate it. I was going off of a lesson which defined an add function with the arguments (x, y) which was why I was typing it that way.

Comment: You're confusing the way you define the calling function and the way it calls the function that it received as an argument. Go reread the lesson.

Comment: I'll bet the lesson does something like `return x() + y()`

Comment: @Barmar Why not add an alternative answer then as it's interesting. Would you call it currying or something else?`

Comment: Hi @Barmar, this is what the lesson provided which may give you insight into why I was confused:
        'def add(x, y):
             return x + y

        def do_twice(func, x, y):
             return func(func(x, y), func(x, y))

        a = 5
        b = 10

        print(do_twice(add, a, b))'

Comment: `do_twice(add, a, b)` doesn't call `add`. It's passing the `add` function to `do_twice`. Functions can be given to other functions.

Comment: Just had an "ah-ha!" moment. I was confusing parameters in defining a function with the arguments of a function. Needless to say it wasn't really clicking until now. Thanks for all the replies and feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is what you want: use the **func** variable to call whatever function is passed in.

```
def sqrt(x):
     return x ** 0.5

def add_function(func, x):
    return func(x) + func(x)

print(sqrt(9))
print(add_function(sqrt, 9))
```

Output:

```
3.0
6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Prune! This is what I was looking for. Just to be clear, would **func** in this case just be an arbitrary word or is that a python standard for calling functions? I'm brand new to coding in general so I do appreciate you answering this low-level question.

Comment: It's just the name of the argument. Name it *foo* (or something else which is valid; valid in terms of python's rules in regards to variable names or shadowing builtin functions, maybe i'm using the wrong terminology here) and try again!

Comment: @pjsansman You can name your variables anything you want. Python won't stop you. However, there is a standard called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which _is_ the standard style guide for Python code. It should try to be adhered to as close as possible.

Comment: Thank you both, I appreciate the feedback and info!

Comment: There are forbidden names, and it's not just about style. E.g. don't name it sum or something starting with numbers.

Comment: @sascha These are different restrictions though. Naming something `sum` is discouraged, naming something `123foo` is impossible.